# PhpStorm won't open xdebug profiler snapshot file

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

=========================================================

**Ignore this post.** A much simpler statement of this issue can be found at [PHP auto_prepend_file causes xdebug profiler to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261449/php-auto-prepend-file-causes-xdebug-profiler-to-fail)

=========================================================

### Original Post (and updates)

When I try to open an xdebug profiler snapshot within PhpStorm using:

> menu bar >> Tools >> Analyze xdebug profiler snapshot...

I select the file xDebug created but I'm faced with this error:

> Error: Incorrect profiler snapshot format: Incorrect name format

I did not rename the snapshot. It is the default name: `cachegrind.out.8008`

**php.ini**

```
<!-- language:lang-none -->
[xdebug]
zend_extension="php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\websites\xdebug"
; xdebug.profiler_output_name= ; Commented out to allow default name
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Why won't PhpStorm open the snapshot? Should I set a custom `xdebug.profiler_output_name` option?

### Update

I closed all my projects, upgraded from PhpStorm `2017.1.4` to `2017.2`, restarted Apache, deleted the old snapshots and created a new one.  <s>The new one opens without trouble.</s>

### Update 2

Seems that if I run a file from the command line by calling `>php script.php`, the generated snapshot can be opened. If I run the same file from the browser (meaning I go through the Apache webserver: `localhost/script.php`) the snapshot cannot be opened.

### Update 3

I also notice that when I execute from the browser, I can't delete the snapshot until I force-stop the Apache process.  The PHP file I'm profiling has no instructions: just `<?php`.  Below are the two snapshots created:

When executed from the command line (PhpStorm opens this file without problem):

```
version: 1
creator: xdebug 2.5.5 (PHP 5.6.1-dev)
cmd: C:\path\to\script.php
part: 1
positions: line

events: Time

fl=(1) C:\path\to\script.php
fn=(1) {main}

summary: 0

1 0
```

When executed from the browser (PhpStorm cannot open this snapshot):

```
version: 1
creator: xdebug 2.5.5 (PHP 5.6.1-dev)
cmd: C:\path\to\script.php
part: 1
positions: line

events: Time

fl=(2) C:\path\to\script.php
fn=(1)

summary: 0

1 0
```

### Update 4

The culprit is the [`auto_prepend_file` ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). I had the following set in Apache Vhosts:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "C:\path\to\init.php"
```

This file is run before Apache executes the script that was called from the browser.  When I run the script from the command line, this setting (which is in my Apache Vhosts config) never takes effect so `init.php` doesn't run. Conversely, if I move the setting to `php.ini` where it also affects command-line execution, then snapshots generated from the command-line also stop working.

If I remove the `auto_prepend_file` setting, the generated profiler snapshot can be open without problem in PhpStorm.  Of course this isn't a fix since I need the `auto_prepend_file` to execute for my application to work properly.

Comment: Am closing this issue, to move discussion to a much better stated problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261449/php-auto-prepend-file-causes-xdebug-profiler-to-fail