# PHP auto_prepend_file causes xdebug profiler to fail

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I use xDebug 2.5.5 on a Windows 7 machine running Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6.  xDebug profiler works ok except when I use a [php auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

in **php.ini**

```
auto_prepend_file = "C:\path\to\init.php"
```

or in **Apache Vhost**

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "C:\path\to\init.php"
```

In either case, adding this directive will cause the generated profiler snapshot *cachegrind.out.####*, to be corrupted somehow.  I cannot open it either in PhpStorm (my IDE) or using [WinCacheGrind](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/). In addition, I cannot delete the snapshot until I kill the Apache process

**WinCacheGrind error**

> Access violation at address 004A5908 in module 'WinCacheGrind.exe'.
>
> Read of address 00000000

**PhpStorm error**

> Incorrect Profiler snapshot format: Incorrect name format

Any advice?

PS: I voted to close my [earlier issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259259/phpstorm-wont-open-xdebug-profiler-snapshot-file) that was misslabeled b/c I thought my problem had to do with PhpStorm not xDebug

Comment: Documentation seems to suggest that setting `xdebug.auto_trace=true` should solve this problem (https://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) - (not something I've tried though)

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you. I tried that before (I've just done it again). That doesn't fix the issue.